# ExtAudioFileOpenURL failure opening audio file from NSTemporaryDirectory()

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, openal, objectal

My app downloads small audio files from my server and stores them in the `NSTemporaryDirectory()`. Then I use `ObjectAL` (which is an OpenAL wrapper library by Karl Stenerud) to place audio in a 3D space. This library uses the `ExtAudioFile` API to open and read audio files, etc. The problem is that it appears `ExtAudioFileOpenURL()` does not allow any files to be read OTHER than local files included in the `[NSBundle mainBundle]`. Is this in fact true? I can successfully open/play audio files with .mp3, .aif, and .caf formats, as long as the file is included in the `-mainBundle`.

If that is in fact the case, is there a way to successfully open an audio file using `ExtAudioFileOpenURL()` that is residing in the `NSTemporaryDirectory()` (or any other iOS file directories? The following gives an overview of relevant code:

```
- (void)setSourceWithSourceURL:(NSString *)urlString type:(CueType)cueType volume:(ALfloat)vol isMono:(BOOL)mono isSFX:(BOOL)isSFX {

    ALSource *source = [self sourceForKey:cueType];
    ALBuffer *buffer = [self bufferForKey:cueType];
    if (!source) {
        source = [[ALSource source] retain];
    }
    if (!buffer) {
        NSArray *array = [urlString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
        NSURL *furl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:array.lastObject]];

        buffer = [[[OpenALManager sharedInstance] bufferFromUrl:furl reduceToMono:mono] retain];
    }
    // fails when setting buffer...
}
```

The `NSLog` output for `furl` before making the `-bufferFromUrl` call is `file:///private/var/mobile/Applications/08E20AF6-6333-4E24-9F12-20C6D6381C0B/tmp/4_right_turn_cue.aif`

I verified that the file does in fact exist...

The `-bufferFromUrl: reduceToMono:` call essentially calls an internal `-init` method:

```
- (id) initWithUrl:(NSURL*) urlIn reduceToMono:(bool) reduceToMonoIn {
    if(nil != (self = [super init])) {
        url = as_retain(urlIn);
        reduceToMono = reduceToMonoIn;

        OSStatus error = 0;
        UInt32 size;

        if(nil == url)
        {
            OAL_LOG_ERROR(@"Cannot open NULL file / url");
            goto done;
        }

        // Open the file
        if(noErr != (error = ExtAudioFileOpenURL((as_bridge CFURLRef)url, &fileHandle)))
        {
            REPORT_EXTAUDIO_CALL(error, @"Could not open url %@", url);
            goto done;
        }
        // ...more stuff but opening the URL fails
```

Once `ExtAudioFileOpenURL()` is called, I get the following error message:

`OAL Error: -[OALAudioFile initWithUrl:reduceToMono:]: Could not open url file:///private/var/mobile/Applications/08E20AF6-6333-4E24-9F12-20C6D6381C0B/tmp/4_right_turn_cue.aif (error code 0x7768743f: Unknown ext audio error)`

Any insights as to why this is failing to read an audio file from a file directory? Any ideas or workarounds?

Comment: have you found solution? I might run into the same problem.